# inline markup / templating engine for customer facing CMS

Tags: scripting, content-management-system, templating

There are many hosted CMS applications that provide you with some sort of inline markup/ templating engine that lets you output things into a page.

for example, a hosted cms application lets you edit your templates to custome html/css, but they also **let you do some basic inline code on the page** to do this like inject the article title, date, etc. (object properties) and let you loop through predefined collections.

How do they do this?

**How do they prevent the user from accessing other objects which you don't want them to?**

e.g. Imaine them outputing your connection string! lol

here is an example: http://wiki.shopify.com/UsingLiquid

Answer (score 1):

Typically the safest way is to create a self-contained scripting language - a runtime within the runtime that has a very limited scope of builtin objects populated by the host runtime, and none of which are dangerous. Obviously a script executing in a runtime cannot reach up outside it's own universe unless the runtime itself provides a mechanism to do so.